# ViewModel not populating correctly after postback

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two listboxes and submit button in my View. There are also arrow buttons in between the listboxes to shift the values from left to right and vice versa. The shifting of the values is handled using Jquery click function. I am concerned with retrieving values from the right most listbox control. Following is the code

Code for list box

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedExchangesIds, new MultiSelectList((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.SelectedExchanges, "Value", "Text"), new { id = "destinationExchanges", name = "destinationExchanges", @style = "width: 250px;height: 144px;", @CssClass = "MyListBox" })
```

Jquery code to shift the values from left to right listbox

```
$('#ShiftUsersRight').click(function (e) {
        $('#sourceUsers option:selected').appendTo('#destinationUsers');
        e.preventDefault();

    });
```

I have also declared a hidden field in the view as follows

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedExchangesIds, "SelectedExchangesIds");
```

The view model that is bound to the view contains the property

```
public IEnumerable<string> SelectedExchangesIds { get; set; }
```

So when I click the submit button on the view, my Edit Action method is called with contains the viewmodel as a parameter. When I check the value of SelectedExchangesIds it is blank string.

On the contrary, if I click on right arrow button which is code named as ShiftUsersRight as seen above, the SelectedExchangesIds property is populated.

How is that happening and why is it not populates when I do not use the button.

My Edit Action button is as follows

```
 [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Edit(SubscriptionViewModel model)
  {
      if (ModelState.IsValid) { }
  }
```

Can some one tell me what is going wrong.

Ok I am copying pasting my entire code below

Code for my view

```
@model Avanade.Bureau.Subscription.Models.SubscriptionViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />

@*<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>*@
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.chkclass').click(function () {

            var getchkid = $(this).attr('id');
            var isChecked = $('#' + getchkid).is(':checked');

            if ($('#' + getchkid).is(':checked') == true) {
                $('#td' + $(this).val()).css("color", "white");
                $('#td' + $(this).val()).css("background-color", "gray");
            }
            else {
                $('#td' + $(this).val()).css("color", "black");
                $('#td' + $(this).val()).css("background-color", "white");
            }
        });


        $('#chk10').click(function (event) {  //on click
            if (this.checked) { // check select status
                $('.chkclass').each(function () { //loop through each checkbox
                    this.checked = true;  //select all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"
                    $('#td' + $(this).val()).css("color", "white");
                    $('#td' + $(this).val()).css("background-color", "gray");
                });
            } else {
                $('.chkclass').each(function () { //loop through each checkbox
                    this.checked = false; //deselect all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"
                    $('#td' + $(this).val()).css("color", "black");
                    $('#td' + $(this).val()).css("background-color", "white");
                });
            }
        });


        $('#sourceUsers').click(function (e) {
            //$("#sourceItems").css("background-color", "gray");
            $('option:selected').css('color', 'white');
            $('option:selected').css('backgroundColor', 'gray');
            //$('#sourceItems option:selected').css("color", "white");
            //$('#sourceItems option:selected').css("background-color", "gray");
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        $('#destinationUsers').click(function (e) {
            //$("#sourceItems").css("background-color", "gray");
            $('option:selected').css('color', 'white');
            $('option:selected').css('backgroundColor', 'gray');
            //$('#sourceItems option:selected').css("color", "white");
            //$('#sourceItems option:selected').css("background-color", "gray");
            e.preventDefault();
        });


        $('#ShiftExchangesRight').click(function (e) {
            $('#sourceExchanges option:selected').appendTo('#destinationExchanges');
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        $('#ShiftExchangesLeft').click(function (e) {
            $('#destinationExchanges option:selected').appendTo('#sourceExchanges');
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        $('#ShiftExchangesRightAll').click(function (e) {
            $('#sourceExchanges option').appendTo('#destinationExchanges');
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        $('#ShiftExchangesLeftAll').click(function (e) {
            $('#destinationExchanges option').appendTo('#sourceExchanges');
            e.preventDefault();
        });


        $('#ShiftUsersRight').click(function (e) {
            $('#sourceUsers option:selected').appendTo('#destinationUsers');
            e.preventDefault();

        });

        $('#ShiftUserssLeft').click(function (e) {
            $('#destinationUsers option:selected').appendTo('#sourceUsers');
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        $('#ShiftUsersRightAll').click(function (e) {
            $('#sourceUsers option').appendTo('#destinationUsers');
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        $('#ShiftUserssLeftAll').click(function (e) {
            $('#destinationUsers option').appendTo('#sourceUsers');
            e.preventDefault();
        });


    });
</script>

<h2>Subscription Details</h2>
<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Edit", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "myForm1", id = "myForm1" }))
    {

        <input type="hidden" id="postedUsers" name="postedUsers" />
        <input type="hidden" id="postedExchanges" name="postedExchanges" />


        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SubscriptionTypeId, "SubscriptionTypeId");
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CompanyId, "CompanyId");




        <div id="test"></div>

        <div class="Table">
            <div class="Row">
                <div class="borderlessCell" style="vertical-align:top">
                    <p>@Html.Label("Subscription Type")</p>
                </div>

                <div class="borderlessCell" style="vertical-align:top">
                    <p>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.SusbcriptionName, new { id = "lblSubscriptionType", name = "lblSubscriptionType" })
                    </p>
                </div>


            </div>

            <div class="Row">
                <div class="borderlessCell">

                </div>
                <div class="borderlessCell">
                    <p>@Html.Label("Available Exchanges")</p>
                </div>
                <div class="borderlessCell">

                </div>
                <div class="borderlessCell">
                    <p>@Html.Label("Selected Exchanges")</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="Row">
                <div class="borderlessCell" style="vertical-align:top">
                    <p>@Html.Label("List of Exchanges")</p>
                </div>
                <div class="borderlessCell" style="vertical-align:top">
                    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.AvailableExchangesIds, new MultiSelectList((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.AvailableExchanges, "Value", "Text"), new { id = "sourceExchanges", name = "sourceExchanges", @style = "width:250px;height: 144px;", @CssClass = "MyListBox" })
                </div>


                <div class="borderlessCell">

                    <div class="Row">
                        <input type="submit" id="ShiftExchangesRight" value=">" style="vertical-align:top" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="Row">
                        <input type="submit" id="ShiftExchangesRightAll" value=">>" style="vertical-align:middle" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="Row">
                        <input type="submit" id="ShiftExchangesLeft" value="<" style="vertical-align:middle" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="Row">
                        <input type="submit" id="ShiftExchangesLeftAll" value="<<" style="vertical-align:bottom" />
                    </div>
                </div>



                <div id="selector" class="borderlessCell">
                    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedExchangesIds, new MultiSelectList((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.SelectedExchanges, "Value", "Text"), new { id = "destinationExchanges", name = "destinationExchanges", @style = "width: 250px;height: 144px;", @CssClass = "MyListBox" })
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="Row">
                <div class="borderlessCell">

                </div>
                <div class="borderlessCell">
                    <p>@Html.Label("Available Users")</p>
                </div>
                <div class="borderlessCell">

                </div>
                <div class="borderlessCell">
                    <p>@Html.Label("Suscribed Users")</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="Row">
                <div class="borderlessCell" style="vertical-align:top">
                    <p>@Html.Label("List of Recipients")</p>
                </div>
                <div class="borderlessCell" style="vertical-align:top">
                    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.AvailableUsersIds, new MultiSelectList((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.AvailableUsers, "Value", "Text"), new { id = "sourceUsers", name = "sourceUsers", @style = "width:250px;height: 144px;", @CssClass = "MyListBox" })
                </div>

                <div class="borderlessCell" style="vertical-align:middle">
                    <p>
                        <input type="submit" id="ShiftUsersRight" value=">" />

                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <input type="submit" id="ShiftUsersRightAll" value=">>" />
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <input type="submit" id="ShiftUsersLeft" value="<" />
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <input type="submit" id="ShiftUsersLeftAll" value="<<" />
                    </p>
                </div>


                <div id="selector" class="borderlessCell">
                    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedUsersIds, new MultiSelectList((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.SelectedUsers, "Value", "Text"), new { id = "destinationUsers", name = "destinationUsers", @style = "width: 250px;height: 144px;", @CssClass = "MyListBox" })
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="Row">

                <div class="borderlessCell">
                    <input type="submit" name="btn_Subscribe" value="Edit" />
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Code of my controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(SubscriptionViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (BUREAUEntities bureauEntities = new BUREAUEntities())
                {
                    string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "," };

                    if (model.SelectedUsersIds != null)
                    {
                        string[] postedUsersArray = model.SelectedUsersIds.ToArray();
                        string[] postedExchangesArray = model.SelectedExchangesIds.ToArray();

                        int[] postedUsers = Array.ConvertAll(postedUsersArray, int.Parse);
                        int[] postedExchanges = Array.ConvertAll(postedExchangesArray, int.Parse);

                        Avanade.Bureau.DataAccessLayer.DatabaseModel.Subscription a = new DataAccessLayer.DatabaseModel.Subscription
                        {
                            SubscriptionTypeId = model.SubscriptionTypeId,
                            IsScheduledNotification = false,
                            Active = true,
                            NotificationFrequencyInMinutes = 12,
                            Exchanges = GetExchanges(postedExchanges, bureauEntities),
                            Users = GetUsers(postedUsers, bureauEntities),
                            CompanyId = model.CompanyId

                        };
                        bureauEntities.Subscriptions.Add(a);
                        bureauEntities.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

Code of my View Model

```
 public class SubscriptionViewModel
    {

        public string PostedUsers { get; set; }
        public string PostedExchanges { get; set; }

        public int SubscriptionId { get; set; }
        public int SubscriptionTypeId { get; set; }
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        public string SusbcriptionName { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string UserSelection { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AvailableExchanges { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectedExchanges { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AvailableUsers { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectedUsers { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<string> AvailableExchangesIds { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> AvailableUsersIds { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> SelectedExchangesIds { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> SelectedUsersIds { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Maybe you could have got an answer if you had learned to mark them as correct!!

Comment: Showing bits and pieces of what you're doing is not too helpful. Please update your question to show a complete example of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Why are you creating a hidden input for `SelectedExchangesIds`? You already have a select for the same property (both with the same name). The model binder will bind to the first and ignore the second.

Comment: Hi @Tieson T. I have pasted my complete code.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke.I have pasted my complete code

Comment: Cant see anywhere in your updated post where you have used `Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedExchangesIds...`? BTW, `<input type="submit"` is for submitting a form. You should use `<button>` instead.

Comment: Hi @ Stephen Muecke. I had removed the HiddenFor field from the code as I was suggested above that if you are already binding it in listbox code then you dont need the hidden for. How does changing submit to button make a difference ?

Answer (score -1):

To solve this problem, you first have to learn how model binder works. It is explained better in the below post:

http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Apr/20/ASPNET-MVC-Postbacks-and-HtmlHelper-Controls-ignoring-Model-Changes

Thanks
Ramakrishna Ganesh

....Happy Coding

Comment: As helpful as this link maybe to everyone, you need to explain it briefly as well